# Road distance travelled between multiple postcodes

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qgis-processing

Is there anyway of using QGIS offline... not using API... I want to calculate road distance travelled between multiple postcodes to single destination.. it works perfectly for small number (200) but software gets crashed or through Python error as I have 3000+ postcodes to measure... I created shape file using MMQGIS->Geocode and for distance travelled calculation used OSM tool.

Comment: did the geocoding crash as well? or just the distance measurement?

Comment: thanks for the reply.. both are crashing...

Comment: you will have to download the osm data via quickOSM or similar and then join tables. after this you can try the OSM tool again or one of the many routing algorithms provided by saga, grass and qgis

Comment: I am trying to download the data using quick OSM but as I am using QGIS3.6, it don't have option download data in vector menu... could you please point me to the steps available for QGIS 3.6 version. and OSM tool is also gone now ORS tool plugin is available and when I am trying to add API key it is throwing an error as Value error : could not convert string to float:None

Comment: quickOSM should work okay in qgis 3.. however if not for you, you can also try https://overpass-turbo.eu/ . you can export the results as geojson and then open it with qgis

Comment: Thanks for reply... I successfully loaded the map in QGIS ... could you please tell me another way of calculating driving distance in bulk without using OSM or ORS tool which requires API key.. using API key giving an error for more than 200 records.. and it has limitation of 2500 per API

Comment: can you be more specific about which distances you want to calculate?

Comment: looking to calculate driving road distance same as you get in google maps... don't want straight line distance between postcodes.

Comment: and do you want to calculate the route from every point to every point?

Comment: I have small shape file for testing which got 10 origin postcode and another file got single target postcode... so result will be all origin postcode to target postcode for eg.O1 - T1, O2 - T1, O3-T1 and so on

Comment: try grass gis v.net.path

Comment: Grass gis v.net.path is another tool? could you please tell me if there is any tutorial or any manual of achieving same using that tool?

Comment: it is a tool in the grass gis plugin for qgis. the manual is here: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.net.path.html